# PHP implementation of CCRYPT

Tags: php, encryption, aes, rijndael

Under linux systems we have **ccrypt** console utility, which **encypt / decrypt** file with some key.

```
ccrypt -e -K 'somekey' somefile // encrypt
ccrypt -d -K 'somekey' somefile // decrypt
```

I need PHP **openssl_encrypt / openssl_decrypt** imlemenatation of this.

On [CCRYPT man page](http://ccrypt.sourceforge.net/ccrypt.html) it said, that ccrypt implements a stream cipher by operating the **Rijndael** block cipher in **CFB** mode and has a block length of 32 bytes or **256** bits.

I was tried the following:

```
$encrypted = file_get_contents('somefile');
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted , 'AES-256-CFB', 'somekey', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
```

But PHP decryption result is not equal to CCRYPT decryption result.

I know it's posible, but i'm stumped. Please help me.

Comment: There is no standard PHP package implementing the ccrypt format, as far as I know. There are 3 possibilities for creating such a PHP routine: (a) add PHP bindings to the existing ccryptlib library, (b) write a ccrypt replacement entirely in PHP, or (c) implement ccrypt's custom key hashing algorithm in PHP, then use mcrypt or another program to do the actual decryption (provided that it supports 256-bit Rijndael, CFB mode, and raw binary keys). `Peter Selinger ` https://sourceforge.net/p/ccrypt/support-requests/3/

Comment: Have you considered using the original ccrypt shell command in your php script?